# Generate pulse signal using optocoupler for steep V/t slopes

Tags: inverter, opto-isolator

My power electronic device has either of these *infeed* waveforms connected in 3-phase:

1. Inverter (+/-325V to +/-720V 16kHz PWM square wave to produce 0-200Hz sine)
2. Standard mains (50/60Hz, 130-540VAC RMS)

I intend to detect positive and negative phase-to-phase edges from (1) and report them to my FPGA with low latency, because responding to the PWM step changes is a control challenge.  The aim is to detect edges for pulses of >320V magnitude with <4us edge.

I have designed a circuit as below.  I would be using Toshiba TLP2367 optocouplers, but I couldn't get a LTSpice model for them, so I simulated with 6N137s.

[image: optoisolated edge detection circuit]

C1 & R1 produce a current pulse for sufficiently steep waveforms.
R2 allows for a faster discharge of C1 to keep the pulses sufficiently short while not over-driving the opto.

OptopPos/OptoNeg: opto output voltage.
Ix(U1:A)/Ix(U2:A): Current into LED anode.

[image: result of simulation, 16kHz +/-325V waveform with 4us slopes]

As far as I can see:

- C1 (several in series?) needs to be rated to 720V+safety margin.
- R1 (several in series?) needs to be rated to 1440V+safety margin.  As worst-case, V1 will flip from +720 to -720 while C1 is positively charged.  Rated for power dissipation according to a crisp +/-720V squarewave.
- All need to be selected to ensure the maximum current through the opto is not exceeded.

It seems like it will work, but I may be naïve to some practical considerations. Have I missed anything?

Comment: What happens when the duty cycle is minimum?

Comment: @Andyaka good point and that is why I wanted to run it by you guys.  Assuming 0.1% PWM minimum, that's 62.5ns which I think can make its way to the FPGA without being filtered out.  The FPGA can detect <10ns width pulses.

Comment: @Andyaka and now I get your question.  What would happen is a screw up.  @ 0.1% PWM (62.5ns), the FPGA can detect the pulses and their time order, but to discharge in time for the negative edge detection, C1 would need a silly value (4.7p).  So I'd say in order to have a designable capacitance (100p+?) I'd be looking at detecting min. 0.5% duty.

Comment: I was actually thinking that very thin pulse widths would never get through the opto-isolators and, I have no idea what Ix(U1:A) is all about relative to your schematic. Opto anode current? You need to look at the opto outputs.

Comment: @Andyaka, as far as I can tell, the opto can do it.  It's pretty special - 50Mbit bandwidth.  https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/TLP2367_datasheet_en_20171025.pdf?did=36692&prodName=TLP2367.  I've been playing around with the values at minimum duty and it seems there's only so much you can accommodate by adjusting three passive components.... I think I will set C1 to the minimum designable (100p?) and work from there.

Comment: Consider that the standard mains also can contain some high voltage burst artefacts.